# É possível pegar a cor de um pixel em um elemento com gradiente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Imagine que eu tenha um elemento `div` com o seguinte CSS:

```
.minha-div{
    width:100px;height:100px;
    background:linear-grandient(45deg, orange, red);
}
```

É possível que quando eu passe o mouse em cima dessa `div`, ele me diga qual a cor do pixel onde o mouse está em cima, utilizando JavaScript / jQuery?

Eu já consegui definir a posição do mouse no bloco colorido, mas não imagino uma forma de pegar a cor naquela exata posição.

Exemplo do que já foi feito: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/vwrMt/)**

Comment: Vale utilizar uma equação à parte (fazendo uma interpolação linear manual para descobrir a cor)?

Comment: Que tipo de conteúdo tem nessa div? Se for apenas uma imagem, você pode usar um canvas. Aí fica mais fácil pegar a cor.

Comment: A idéia é criar uma espécie de *color-picker* próprio, mas com CSS, então o conteúdo dessa `div` seria o mesmo, mas as cores podem vir a mudar.

Answer (score 1):

Com uma consulta em alguns tópicos, não encontrei nenhuma forma de fazer isso utilizando somente css + javascript, porem vi alguns exemplos utilizando canvas. 
Segue um exemplo no [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/svLZ5/)

Fontes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202476/how-can-i-get-the-color-of-any-specified-pixel-on-a-web-page

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735470/get-pixel-color-from-canvas-on-mouseover